# MySQL Finding column values in rows

Tags: mysql

I have a scenario where I need to match values in columns of one table with rows in another.

I have two tables: employee_id and id_entries.

employee_id has the following structure:

```
    employee_id     id_1    id_2
    1               123      456
    2               789      120
    3               345      678
    4               901      234
```

id_entries has the following structure:

```
    employee_name   id_number
    John Doe          123
    Jane Smith        789
    John Doe          456
    Jane Smith        120
```

I want to be able to match the employee_id field in the employee_id table to employee_name in the id_entries table where there is an entry for both id_1 and id_2.

For example

```
    employee_id     employee_name    id_1    id_2
    1               John Doe         123     456
    2               Jane Smith       789     120
```

I've tried several different joins but haven't been able to bring back the correct results.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like an odd scenario. What's happened here?

Comment: Is `id_number` **unique** in  `id_entries` table?

Comment: simply inner join can do it for you.

Comment: Thanks. Very odd scenario. IDs were created that were found to be not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join it to two instances of id_entries table, one for each id column:

```
select 
    employee_id, a.employee_name, id_1, id_2 
from 
    employee_id 
inner join 
    id_entries as a on employee_id.id_1 = a.id_num
inner join 
    id_entries as b on employee_id.id_2 = b.id_num
where 
    a.employee_name = b.employee_name
```